# Duplicate object in a list when I try to map all related entities

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

According to this [post](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/06/mapping-query-entities-sdn.html) I tried to map all related entities in a list.
I used the same query into the post with a condition to return a list of User but it returns duplicate object

`MATCH (user:User) WHERE <complex conditions> 
WITH user, calculatedValue 
MATCH p=(user)-[r*0..1]-() RETURN user, calculatedValue, nodes(p), rels(p)`

Is it a bug? I'm using SDN 4.2.4.RELEASE with neo4j 3.2.1

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I use OPTIONAL clause as suggested

Comment: Ok, so the entities get hydrated then? It did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug.

Keep in mind a MATCH in Neo4j will find all occurrences of a given pattern. Let's look at your last MATCH:

```
MATCH p=(user)-[r*0..1]-()
```

Because you have a variable match of `*0..1`, this will always return at least one row with just the `user` itself (with `rels(p)` empty and `nodes(p)` containing only the `user`), and then you'll get a row for every connected node (`user` will always be present on that row, and in the `nodes(p)` collection, along with the other connected node).

In the end, when you have a single `user` node and `n` directly connected nodes, you will get `n + 1` rows. You can run the query in the Neo4j browser, looking at the table results, to confirm.

A better match might be something like:

```
...
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r]-(b)
RETURN user, calculatedValue, collect(r) as rels, collect(b) as connectedNodes
```

Because we aggregate on all relationships and connected nodes (rather than just the relationships and nodes for each path), you'll get a single row result per `user` node.

Comment: Your solution returns the correct numbers of object but they are not hydrated (all related entities of user are not mapped)